# Create a new cluster in Databricks using databricks-cli

Tags: bash, azure, command-line-interface, databricks, databricks-cli

I'm trying to create a new cluster in Databricks on Azure using databricks-cli.

I'm using the following command:

```
databricks clusters create --json '{ "cluster_name": "template2", "spark_version": "4.1.x-scala2.11" }'
```

And getting back this error:

```
Error: {"error_code":"INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE","message":"Missing required field: size"}
```

I can't find documentation on this issue, would be happy to receive some help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the right answer [here](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/api/latest/clusters.html).

The correct format to run this command on azure is:

```
databricks clusters create --json '{ "cluster_name": "my-cluster", "spark_version": "4.1.x-scala2.11", "node_type_id": "Standard_DS3_v2", "autoscale" : { "min_workers": 2, "max_workers": 50 } }'
```

Comment: Yes however this creates Multi mode cluster. If you need to create single node cluster different set of parameters you need to pass

Comment: I used the API and it worked like a charm, I used it to clone an existing cluster and just had to rename and remove the cluster_id. Btw, your link is not working anymore. https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/clusters/create

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to the answer that @MorShemesh gave, you can also use a path to a JSON file instead of specifying the JSON at the command line.

```sh
databricks clusters create --json-file /path/to/my/cluster_config.json
```

If you are managing lots of clusters this might be an easier approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
databricks clusters create --json "{ "cluster_name": "custpm-cluster", "spark_version": "4.1.x-scala2.09", "node_type_id": "Standard_DS3_v2", "autoscale" : { "min_workers": 2, "max_workers": 50 }}"
```

Comment: this is incorrect answer...